# C error, simple scanf functions with integers giving 0 as result

Tags: c, integer, printf, scanf

I'm experimenting and training some C and I found out a very strange "error" that I can't understand.

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int num1, num2;
    int num3 = num1 * num2;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("Enter one more number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    printf("The result of %d * %d is %d\n", num1, num2, num3);
}
```

I want it to assume that the variable num3 is the product between num1 and num2.

I got this output:

```
Enter a number: 8
Enter one more number: 7
The result of 8 x 7 is 0
```

Numbers `8` and `7` are random numbers I typed in.

Why is it `0`? It is supposed to be `56`.

Comment: Put this line `int num3 = num1 * num2;` after the second `scanf()`.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It's working !

Answer (score 1):

You are computing num3, even before num1 and num2 have been read in from the command line. Assuming, num1 and num2 were initialized to zero num3 would be zero at the time of computation.

Comment: I got the point, I didn't know it could cause a problematic situation.
Thank you !

Comment: C falls under a general class of languages called "Imperative" Languages. In these languages computation is performed in the order in which the statements are written - also known as the program order.

Comment: Ty for the info !

Answer (score 1):

Filipe, you have got to *put the horse before the cart*. Variables must be *initialized with a value* before you multiply them together. (in fact, attempting to access a value in an uninitialized variable invokes *Undefined Behavior* (that's bad....)

Just what do you expect to happen in the following code?

```
int num1, num2;
int num3 = num1 * num2;
```

What values are contained in `num1`, `num2`? What do you think will get put in `num3`? In instances like this it is really a good idea to see [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and talk to the duck... Really, it helps `:)`

Next there is *unvalidated user input*, e.g.

```
scanf ("%d", &num1);
```

What happens if the user enters `"one"` (or a cat steps on the keyboard)? Always, always validate user input. `scanf` ***returns*** the number of successful conversions that take place. In the case of `"%d"` -- that's `1` if the command successfully places an integer value in `num1`. A simple test can save a lot of grief, e.g.

```
    printf ("Enter a number: ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &num1) != 1) { /* validate ALL user input */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input or user canceled.\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

By checking that the returns of `scanf` is `1`, you protect against both *matching* and *input* failures (see: `man scanf`).

Only after you have successfully placed values in `num1` and `num2` can you validly multiply `num1` and `num2` together, e.g.

```
    num3 = num1 * num2; /* num1 & num2 must have values first */
```

Putting all the pieces together, the *horse before the cart*, and noting that `main()` is type `int` and therefore should `return` a value **<sup>[1]</sup>**, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int num1, num2, num3;

    printf ("Enter a number: ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &num1) != 1) { /* validate ALL user input */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input or user canceled.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("Enter one more number: ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &num2) != 1) { /* Ditto */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input or user canceled.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    num3 = num1 * num2; /* num1 & num2 must have values first */

    printf ("The result of %d * %d is %d\n", num1, num2, num3);

    return 0;   /* main() is type int and returns a value. */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/multiply
Enter a number: 8
Enter one more number: 7
The result of 8 * 7 is 56
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

**footnote[1]** See: [**C11 Standard §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup (draft n1570)**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). See also: [**See What should main() return in C and C++?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Comment: Dude... thank you... I don't have words..
One more question, how can I change the code in the "if" part of the age to give an error when someone gives a negative age ? I mean, I can use and unsigned variable but that doesn't change because it will give me a strange value.

Comment: `if (scanf ("%d", &age) != 1 || age < 0) /* {handle error} */`

Answer (score 0):

You could also add num3 to first init then after prompting the user to enter numbers have the line num3=num1*num2;